# TypeScript and tweaking values (wait for refresh until file has been compiled)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, compilation

I'm in love with TypeScript, but I don't know really how to handle tweaking of values. I'm talking about subtle changes, changes in i.e. the *feel* of touch controls or animations.

While working on projects in Visual Studio, usually the process is the same. Make a tweak - go to the browser, hit refresh, wait and see the result.

With TypeScript the process is different. The TypeScript file is being compiled in the background and IIS *will happily serve the old version while the new file is being generated*.

This means that you're never **really** sure what values you are watching it. Did it already recompile or not? Am I looking at the old values or the new values?

I really would like to see that when I press save and hit refresh, the generated .js file blocks loading until it's the newly compiled version - just like with any HTML tweak.

Is there any way to do this? Any recommendations? These are my settings:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "none",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "../Scripts/type-script.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

- this also influences simple bugfixes sometimes - didn't I fix the bug? Or am I still looking at an older version of the script?
- even worse; sometimes TypeScript (within VS) just seems to actually stop compiling at all. This costs quite some time to figure out, getting me completely out of *the flow*.
- I'm looking for something that doesn't destroy too much the rest of my flow. Manually running a compile command after every save would feel like a regression.

Comment: Dear downvoter, how is this too broad? I'm looking for an explicit fix. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [Browsersync](https://browsersync.io/) would be of interest? Plus, tools like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) and [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) have hot module reloading built-in, if ever you want to bundle up your code using a proper module system